# how to perform robust control on combined (electrical and mechanical) system in matlab or simulink

Tags: matlab, controls, robust

I'm trying to perform **robust control** on my plant model. i have seen examples on robust control performed on **electrical system (motor)** and **mechanical system (spring mass damper)** but i haven't seen if the systems are combined. Also I'm using **linear quadratic regulator** for feedback instead of **proportional–integral–derivative controller**. Also i modeled mech& electrical system in state space. Any valuable inputs on how to perform robust control would be appreciated

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Had you tried also Gaussian control(LQG)? or a method with a full-observer?